# In VSS 2005, how do I move a project (and all associated folders and files) under another project?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Last Friday I started a project in Visual Studio 2012. We use Visual SourceSafe 2005 for our source control. I wish I hadn't done this, but I did, when I created the project in VSS 2005, I put it at the root level. I didn't realize my mistake until today. We have a root level project that would have been much more appropriate to have put this into, but I didn't do that.

So here are my questions. First, is it possible to move a project in VSS 2005's Visual SourceSafe Explorer, from one place (the root level) to another place (under a different root level folder)? Where it is on any of our development machines is a different issue, I just want to move this project, within VSS, to where it should be, where other developers will look for find it.

Second, if it is possible to do this, then how do I do it?

Comment: Why on earth are you still using VSS if you have moved on to VS 2012? There are plenty of free and paid source control systems that work much better.

Comment: Lack or time to change to anything else. We're always under the gun to get something done. Yes, it would be great to use something else, but that's so low on our priorities. And yes, I feel bad bringing it up and admitting that we're still using VSS. Oh well, here it is, we're behind the times and without the backing to pursue anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the steps below:

1. In Visual SourceSafe Explorer, you can use the menu File->Move command to move your project.
2. In Visual Studio, please go to File->Source Control->Change Source Control and update the mapping  to make sure it uses the new server path.